# CGEvent NSKeyDown only working if app is front most?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nsevent, cgeventtap

I am trying to automate some tasks (there's no applescript support) so I have to use CGEvents and post these events. Mouse clicking works fine, but NSKeyDown (enter) only works if I click on the app in the dock(which makes it front most app)...
Here's my code so far:

```
   for (NSDictionary *dict in windowList) {
        NSLog(@"%@", dict);
        if ([[dict objectForKey:@"kCGWindowName"] isEqualToString:@"Some Window..."]) {
            WIDK = [[dict objectForKey:@"kCGWindowNumber"] intValue];
            break;
        };
    }


    CGEventRef CGEvent;
    NSEvent *customEvent;

    customEvent = [NSEvent keyEventWithType:NSKeyDown 
                                   location:NSZeroPoint 
                              modifierFlags:0 
                                  timestamp:1 
                               windowNumber:WIDK
                                    context:nil 
                                 characters:nil 
                charactersIgnoringModifiers:nil 
                                  isARepeat:NO 
                                    keyCode:36];

    CGEvent = [customEvent CGEvent];
    for (int i=0; i <5; i++) {
        sleep(3);
        CGEventPostToPSN(&psn, CGEvent);
        NSLog(@"posted the event");
    }

    CFRelease(eOne);
```

The reason why I have posteventtopsn in a loop is for testing purposes (I just need it to send it once). While the program is in the loop, if I activate my app to front most, then the event works fine.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way it can work if it in background? Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean that you want your app in the background, or you want to send events to the app in the background?

Comment: Is this code (with the loop and `sleep`) in the same app to which you're trying to send the events?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. 
@Josh - No, it's not running on the same app. 
@Nathan - I want to send events to the app in the background. Mouse click works fine, but nskeydown only works if i make it the front most app.

Comment: @user635064 Is it possible that the app was written to ignore events when it is in the background? If so, there won't be a lot that you can do...

Comment: Is the goal here to script a third-party application, i.e., one over whose code you have no control? Apps don't act on key events when they're in the background. They have to install an event tap or monitor to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a better way to post keyboard events to the front-most application:

```
  CGEventRef a = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(NULL, 124, true);
  CGEventRef b = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(NULL, 124, false);
  CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, a);
  CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, b);
```

CGEventPost lets you determine where the event is posted. I used this code recently to allow someone to remotely control a PPT presentation on my laptop. (Character 124 is the right arrow key.)

Note that you should be freeing the event after posting it.

You can send to a specific app (eg not the front app) by using CGEventPostToPSN.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the reply. This is essentially the same thing I am doing, but I tried your way and still getting the same thing. Only works if the app is the front most..Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

i think it's because you create a NSEvent using "WIDK" for parameter windowNumber , and WIDK is related to your app only.